What is "skinning" in advanced integration techniques?
Apparently there is an integration method called "skinning" for definite integrals. 
There are literally journal articles about it, but nowhere else...
Here are the journals I found: 
"Four Ways to Skin a Definite Integral"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.4169/074683410X480249

"Yet More Ways to Skin a Definite Integral"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/college.math.j.47.1.11

"A Fifth Way to Skin a Definite Integral"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/college.math.j.43.5.377

"An Unorthodox Approach to Skinning a Definite Integral"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07468342.2022.2011543

"Further Integral Skinning with Applications"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07468342.2018.1507383

"On that most over Skinned of Improper Integrals"
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/07468342.2023.2186085
Unfortunately, I don't have access to any of the articles. But it's been really bugging me like hell. 
Seriously, what on earth is skinning??? I would like to see some examples.

It's probably an allusion to this idiom, not a technical term. If I'm right, to skin an integral is to evaluate it.

Obviously the term 'to skin', remove the skin of an animal, also used to remove the isolation of a wire, means to find the inner structure of a real integral by  looking at the complex antiderivative as an integral over a closed contour by Cauchy's theorems.

@RolandF I don't think it's limited to contour integration. The "unorthodox approach" avoids doing so, but is still described as skinning.

I downloaded the article, there is no repetition of the word "skin" after the  title.  They just illustrate four methods to integrate $1/ (1+x^2)$
